# 3D polar chart in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, 3d, polar-coordinates

**Background**

I have a set of financial data I am trying to analyze and display graphically. The data consists of high resolution price data for a number of commodity contracts. These contracts are specified by having both a product (the actual commodity in question) and a tenor (a specified delivery date for the contract). The combination of a product and tenor therefore gives a fully defined commodity contract, which has a current market price, as follows

```
     T              Product 1                    Product 2           
 --------- ---------------------------- ---------------------------- 
  Tenor 1   $ Commodity contract price   $ Commodity contract price  
            for product 1 at tenor 1     for product 2 at tenor 1    
  Tenor 2   $ Commodity contract price   $ Commodity contract price  
            for product 1 at tenor 2     for product 1 at tenor 2
```

Using some example data, looking at the September, October and November contracts for two grades of crude oil, Brent and WTI, and the current market prices would give us something like this.

```
      T        Brent      WTI    
 ----------- --------- --------- 
  Sep 2020    $37.25    $33.40   
  Oct 2020    $38.10    $33.75   
  Nov 2020    $38.85    $34.15
```

But of course these prices aren’t static as they are moving with market forces, so we have a snapshot of these prices every t seconds. Let’s say the above is our starting point, but at t+1 Brent prices have moved a dollar and WTI by 50c, so our prices now look like this

```
    T + 1      Brent      WTI    
 ----------- --------- --------- 
  Sep 2020    $38.25    $33.90   
  Oct 2020    $39.10    $34.25   
  Nov 2020    $39.85    $34.65
```

This is broadly the structure of the dataset, though the scope is of course much larger.

**What I am trying to do and how far I have gotten**

I have a specific visualization of this data (or subsets thereof) that I have been working towards. I am trying to produce what I would call a 3D or extruded polar chart, which would have contract values for different products as the distance from the centre of the polar chart, would extend along the Z-axis to represent the different tenors, and that would animate to display the change in contract values over time. I have achieved 2/3rds of this using the polar chart function of ploty express, to produce a 2D animated polar chart that displays the contract values for 6 products for 1 tenor over time. The following two images show two frames from this chart

[June14 contract price for Brent, WTI, barges, 180, 380, GC on date of 2014-02-14](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wrCK.png)

[June14 contract price for Brent, WTI, barges, 180, 380, GC on date of 2014-03-27](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omdxO.png)

However, as far as I can tell this function cannot be extended to 3d, so I think I do have to start fresh. A diagram of what I’m trying to achieve is as follows:

[Desired result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0WLk8.png)

I am aiming for a result similar to a very basic Streamtube (see https://plotly.com/python/streamtube-plot/?_ga=2.134282552.895284899.1586457324-1038545846.1585071729 and https://medium.com/plotly/streamtubes-in-plotly-with-python-and-r-a30216ef20a3), but the cross sectional polygon shape of a streamtube seems to always have a fixed radius for each point from the centre, not varying as in my use case, so I don’t believe I can use this pre-built function. Additionally these work using vector fields to draw the plot, so there would be some complex and unhelpful reverse engineering of my data to produce the correct inputs, which indicates to me that this is the wrong route. I believe my best bet is using contour maps in either matplotlib or ploty, but I have hit a bit of brick wall on how to do this.

Any suggestions would be very appreciated.